# Interop Excel Range Formula assignment with string concatenation

Tags: c#, excel, string, excel-formula, excel-interop

When try to assign a concatenated string to Range.Formula, doesn't works, but simple string do perfectly.

Working code:

```
string formula = string.Format("=Round1!D{0} + Round2!D{0}", cellId); 
myRange.Formula = formula;
```

Failing code:

```
string formula = string.Format("=Round{0}!D{1}!", 1, cellId);
for (int i = 2; i <= numRounds; i++)
    formula += string.Format(" + Round{0}!D{1}!", i, cellId);
myRange.Formula = formula;
```

¿WTF? xD

This makes imposible to generate the formula dinamicly

Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the `!` at the end - `"=Round{0}!D{1}"`

Comment: wow embarrasing mistake! thank you! Should i remove this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string formula = string.Format("=Round{0}!D{2} + Round{1}!D{2}", 1, 2 cellId); 
myRange.Formula = formula;
```

If the sheets `Round1` to `Round3` (`numRounds`) are in order in the Workbook, then you can use [3-D reference](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/3d-reference.html). For example:

```
= Sum( Round1:Round3!D3 )
```

which will be the same as

```
= Round1!D3 + Round2!D3 + Round3!D3
```

Comment: doesn't should be:
    string formula = string.Format("=Round{0}!D{1}", 1, cellId);
    formula += string.Format("=Round{0}!D{1}", 2, cellId);
?
Fix it and I'll mark as solved

Comment: @evega but that will turn into for example `"=Round1!D3=Round2!D3"`. Do you want to compare them or add them ?

Comment: ok wait, thats because is a example fragment. Let me post all the code.